# iText Arabic flipped and re-arranged with RTL

Tags: itext, arabic, bidirectional, bidi

I am having an issue with certain mixed arabic/English data.
Here is the code I use:

```
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent()); 
column.setSimpleColumn(36, 770, 569, 36); 
column .setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);      
column.setArabicOptions(column.AR_NOVOWEL |                  
                      column.AR_LIG |                      
                      column.AR_COMPOSEDTASHKEEL);
```

This the original Data

2  ‏ ‏ ‎تغــيير ‎3010 E02‎

Data after pdf generation

E02 3010 رييغت   ‎2

If I change to column.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI)
the line comes out correct but the arabic is unshaped.

Comment: This article might help you http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/02/15/unicode-characters-dropped-in-pdf-files-generated-with-itext-and-flying-saucer/

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct. The numbers are neutral and will follow the current direction. In this example we start with R for the number 2 then R for the arabic then R for the number 3010 then L for E02.

Comment: If I specify column.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI) then the line is arranged as the original, but the arabic is unshaped. Is   there a way to have the characters shaped in this case?

Comment: Maybe you want `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR`. It will shape the arabic but keep the latin order.

Comment: Or could I also use ArabicLigaturizer()  with  RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI?

Comment: With ´RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI´ the arabic won't be shaped.

Comment: The question is whether you want "Latin text with some Arabic" or "Arabic text with some Latin text". In the first case you use LTR, in the second RTL. As @PauloSoares said, NO_BIDI will create incorrect, non-ligaturized Arabic text.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM bidi layout and the iText bidi processing seemed to be interfering with each other.I used RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI and used the JAVABIDI flags here: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/bidirectional/JAVABIDI.html
Now the iText PDF arabic is perfect in all cases.

However I am now having an issue with the PDF Metadata, which is now showing the same flipping issue when I have mixed Arabic/Latin data there, is there a way to turn off the bidi at the Metadata level?